# Why third person rules do not work for 'him run'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> I watched him play the match.
>
> I saw him run away towards the forest.

Why not 'runs' and 'plays' is used for that 'him'?

Comment: They're infinitives, with their subjects raised to objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verbs *see, hear, watch* and *feel* are followed either by an *object + base form* (infinitive without *to*) to talk about a completed action, or *object + -**ing*** form to talk about an action in progress.

This is why your sentences are correct:

> I watched him **play** the match. (NOT <s>*I watched him plays the match*.</s>)
>   I saw him **run** away towards the forest. (NOT <s>*I saw him runs away towards the forest*.</s>)